# 404 error on subcategory pages

Tags: categories, permalinks, htaccess

I have seen some other questions and answers on this but unable to resolve at the moment.

I have some categories setup as follows:

> Blog
>
> -- Sub Cat

The Permalinks are currently setup with custom type: `/%category%/%postname%/` and the category base is set to `.`

**At the moment**

- If I go to a post in a subcategory it works.
- Accessing the parent blog category works.
- Accessing the child category **does not work**

I have tried changing the permalinks to the following `/%category%/%subcategory%/%postname%/`.

This causes the following behaviour:

- Main Blog category access works.
- Sub Category access works.
- Post within subcategory **does not work**.

Note: The link it tries to take me to is the following:

> /blog/sub-cat-name/%subcategory%/long-post-name-or-something/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of this issue for future reference was the '.' in the category base, which was added to resolve a previous issue. Removing this and using /category/postname (per question) works, so will look for an alternative resolution to the category base issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your permalinks, adding some extension at the end:

```
/%category%/%postname%.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, Permalink > Common Settings > Custom Structure

Use this slug: `/%category%/`

Select only sub-category for the post.  There is no need to select Parent Category for a post.

Comment: This does not work, the permalinks to the posts then lead to the sub category instead of the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using Yoast SEO plugin**.

I had a similar problem which I solved by downloading and activating the Yoast SEO plugin, then on the main dashboard:

Yaost SEO > Settings > Categories and Tags > Categories > Additional settings.

disable "Show the categories prefix in the slug".

Answer (score -1):

## Workaround

**Settings** > **Permalinks** > **Common Settings**

*Custom Structure* `/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/`

**Settings** > **Permalinks** > **Optional**

*Category base* `.`

Tested with WordPress version 4.8

Comment: This solution does not work anymore. It breaks the blog.

Comment: @JackJohansson I added which WordPress version to the answer, thanks for the suggestion.