# Accessible Subcategory URL's pages without using .php hack

Tags: categories, permalinks, urls, htaccess

I'm attempting to setup a custom URL structure within posts that makes all parents and sub child's accessible, but all attempts have failed with various errors.

*My category structure looks something like this:*

1. `- Cars`
2. `-- Mondeo`
3. `--- 1994`
4. `---- Postname`

*The idea is that people can access the following pages:*

- `example.com/cars/`
- `example.com/cars/mondeo/`
- `example.com/cars/mondeo/1994/`
- `example.com/cars/mondeo/1994/postname/`

Postname (the article will be added to all categories listed above and the primary will be set to the last sub catagory listed).

*What I've tried:*

- Setting permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/` this results in 404's when attempting to visit `/cars/mondeo/` or `/cars/mondeo/1994/`. This however works when visiting `/cars/` and `/cars/mondeo/1994/postname/`.
- Using `/%category%/%subcategory%/%postname%/` as the permalinks makes the sub categories work, but then breaks the parents and the postnames... not good.

*.htaccess / mod_rewrite is enabled and working:*

I have tested the .htaccess adding a deny, i.e:

```
# Test HTACCESS
Deny from all 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END Word
```

*I hate the .php method, surely there is a better way...*

The only solutions I've been able to find on here are by using a [dirty .php method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209886/404-error-on-subcategory-pages), which seems silly, I cant believe that WordPress can't handle this and I imagine that this has been asked in various forms and I've not found them, in which case please kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: Basically, you have a situation where multiple types of things match the same rewrite pattern. WordPress has to know if you're asking for a post or a category *before* it goes and queries for it. That's why the `.php` method works, it adds a unique element to the pattern that will only match posts. [Have a look at this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177010/how-to-check-if-last-uri-segment-is-a-custom-post-type-or-taxonomy-term) which is a similar issue, you have to do a bit of work yourself to help WordPress know what you're asking for.

Comment: Hey @Milo, oh right, can this be done just in the .htaccess or does it require a bit of both? I've looked at the post and I kinda understand it to some degree, that WordPress needs to be told what it is.